# Does Yom Kippur atone for the transgression of (not) honoring parents?

Tags: halacha, yom-kippur, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

Following my previous question [division-between-interpersonal-and-god-related-mitzvot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/120904/definition-and-origin-of-the-division-between-interpersonal-and-god-related-mitz) (please read the background):

Does Yom Kippur alone atone for the transgression of (not) honoring one's parents as if it was God-related Mitzvah and no parents' forgiveness would be required?

Comment: Please note the definition of the [halacha-theory tag](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/halacha-theory/info): "Questions about theoretical issues about psak and general halacha concepts." It's not for hypothetical Halacha questions; it's for meta-Halacha. Please don't use it for the former.

Comment: It sounds like this question is asking whether Kibud Av Va'eim is considered an interpersonal Mitzvah or a Mitzvah between man and G-d (which would affect what sort of Teshuvah one would need to do). If that is what you're asking, please clarify that in your post. And from what I seem to recall, it's a debate as to what the Mitzvah of Kibud Av is classified as.

Comment: @Alberko be sure to see my new answer updated [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/120984/17072). I think you will like it.

Answer (score -3):

According to conservative rabbi, Benjamin Sendrow, the commandment to “Honor your father and your mother” is the number one commandment, the most important commandment of Judaism in the “Ten Commandments”, commonly known as the Decalogue. He writes that evidence of this is that this commandment helps fight against narcissism.

Rabbi Sendrow explains that to “Honor your father and your mother” [is] the most important of the Ten Commandments." In fact, the essay he wrote was about this commandment and Yom Kippur. A curious read will show that the sin can be atoned on Yom Kippur, in his view.[1]

[1] Read full essay [here](http://shaareytefilla.org/uploads/honoryourfatherandmother.pdf)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120792/discussion-between-turk-hill-and-salmononius2).